# aircrack-ng issue: No mon0 when run "airmon-ng start wlan0" and "No such BSSID available"

Tags: wifi, kali-linux, aircrack-ng

I have read many threads on StackExchange and some other blogs but none helped me. The issue is with `aircrack-ng` on Kali Linux. It gives me error **No such BSSID available** when I run `aireply-ng`. I think it is because of not having mon0 when I run `airmon-ng`.

```
root@kali:~# uname -a
Linux kali 4.19.0-kali1-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.19.13-1kali1 (2019-01-03) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I have updated the driver of usb wifi adaptor; RTL8812AU and it is the output of `iwconfig`.

```
root@kali:~# iwconfig
eth0      no wireless extensions.

lo        no wireless extensions.

wlan0     IEEE 802.11  Mode:Monitor  Frequency:2.422 GHz  Tx-Power=18 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
```

I think it needs to show the name of the adapter in the monitor mode, something like `mon0` or `wlanmon0` but it shows only 3 or some other numbers.

```
root@kali:~# airmon-ng start wlan0

PHY Interface   Driver      Chipset

phy0    wlan0       88XXau      Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTL8812AU 802.11a/b/g/n/ac WLAN Adapter

        (mac80211 monitor mode already enabled for [phy0]wlan0 on [phy0]3)
```

I have read on some blogs that it does not really matter if there is no `mon0`; but it doesn't work at all and just give me the following error, **No such BSSID available**.

```
root@kali:~# aireplay-ng --deauth 100 -a MAC_OF_AP -c MAC_OF_TARGET wlan0
16:56:02  Waiting for beacon frame (BSSID: MAC_OF_AP) on channel 3
16:56:12  No such BSSID available.
```

P.S.
- I have tested it on Windows 10 and Ubuntu 18.10 hosts as well as Kali 2019 and ParrotSec. Both have the same issue.

Comment: Are you actually setting `MAC_OF_AP` and `MAC_OF_TARGET` to the correct values in your aireplay-ng command?

Comment: Did you run `airmon-ng check kill` before `airmon-ng start wlan0`?

Comment: Are you on the right channel? I see that the AP is on channel 3, and when you started airmon you selected no channel, try `airmon-ng start wlan0 3` Also before that do the check kill command as @they suggested.

Answer (score 2):

In your output for airmon-ng, it says that monitor mode has been enabled for [phy0]3. This means that a new interface named 3 has been created which is using monitor mode.Therefore, 3 is the interface you should use along with aireplay or any other tools of the aircrack-ng suite. Try:

```
aireplay-ng --deauth 100 -a MAC_OF_AP -c MAC_OF_TARGET 3
```

Answer (score 2):

There are a few adjustments that you can make to the airmon-ng configuration. I recommend that you run through this process to ensure you can pick up your monitor interface.

- Start with viewing your interfaces with a quick iwconfig

  `root@kali:~# iwconfig`
- Once you view the interface you want, ensure in the interface details that the mode is set to monitor or managed "Mode:Monitor".

I noticed that your interface "wlan0" was already set to monitor, which is why you got the message "(mac80211 monitor mode already enabled for [phy0]wlan0 on [phy0]3)"

If it is set to managed, bring it up with airmon-ng, although remember best to set the channel else you'll just get something random.

- Set the Monitor mode with

  `root@kali:~# airmon-ng start wlan0 1`
- Then try an airodump to confirm you can sniff packets with

  `root@kali:~# airodump-ng -c 1 wlan0mon` (check iwconfig since wlan0 may either be in monitor mode already, or will switch when you perform a airmon-ng start command).

There doesn't seem to be a configuration issues with your aircrack-ng suite. Please try the above and advise if you're still having issues.

Best of luck!